# Write a method that takes an array of numbers in. Your method should # return the third greatest number in the array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have:

```
def third_greatest(nums)
  highest_num_array = []
  highest_num = 0
  i = 0

  while highest_num_array.length < 3
    while i < nums.length
      if nums[i] > highest_num
        highest_num = nums[i]
      end
      i = i + 1
    end
    nums.delete(highest_num)
    highest_num_array.push(highest_num)
  end

  return highest_num_array[2]
end
```

I keep getting the highest number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `nums.sort[-3]` a solution for this problem?

Comment: @spickermann Unless you want to do it yourself for fun

Comment: I'm just a beginner. We haven't gone over the sort method yet

Answer (score 1):

`highest_num` is not renullified after each of the outer loops. Therefore it will remain the highest number in the list and will just get pushed in the array three times.

If you put the

```
highest_num = 0
```

after

```
while highest_num_array.length < 3
```

it should work.

---

Even then, there are a lot of problems with your code:

- It doesn't look like Ruby at all.
- You are mutating the list that was passed as argument.
- You don't handle the case when values can be repeating.
- You assume numbers to be `> = 0`.

All you wanted was

```
numbers.max(3).last
```

Comment: Just a note that it was Ruby v2.2 that permitted [Enumerable#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) to have an argument. (Same for `max_by` and `min_by`).